# How to efficiently get stream from EmguCV (OpenCV) image

Tags: opencv, pointers, stream, unmanaged, emgucv

I have an `EmguCV.Image<Brg, Byte>()` instance and another 3rd party API, that requires `Stream` that represents the image data.

I was able to convert the EmguCV image to the stream and pass it to the 3rd party API using `System.Drawing.Bitmap.Save` but that is not very efficient.

**How to get the stream as afficietnly as possible?**

This code works:

```
var image = new Image<Rgb, byte>("photo.jpg");
var bitmap = image.Bitmap// System.Drawing - this takes 108ms!
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp); //not very efficient either
   ms.Position = 0;
   return ImageUtils.load(ms); //the 3rd party API
}
```

I have tried to create `UnmanagedMemoryStream` directly from the image:

```
byte* pointer = (byte*)image.Ptr.ToPointer();
int length = image.Height*image.Width*3;
var unmanagedMemoryStream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream(pointer, length);
```

but when i try to read from it, it throws an `AccessViolationException`: Attempted to read or write protected memory.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   //throw AccessViolationException at random interation, e.g i==82240, 79936, etc
   unmanagedMemoryStream.ReadByte();     
}
```

the length is 90419328 in this case and it shoudl be correct, because it has the same value as image.ManagedArray.Length;

How to get the stream without copying the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there is Bytes property of type byte[] on the Image() so the answer is very easy:

```
new MemoryStream(image.Bytes)
```